# Ajax callback from two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello i have a problem with ajax and two callbacks code look like that

```
loadTasks(function(tasks) {
    taskhtml = whatStatus(tasks);
    loadSupportList(function(tasks) {
        supporthtml = support(tasks);
        $("#devtask-table").html(
                titleDraw() + "<tbody>" + supporthtml + taskhtml
                        + "</tbody>");
        hideCurtain();
    });
});
```

And it's work fine when loadSupportList or loadTasks have records. But when one of them don't i get Error, status = parsererror, error thrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input. And it jump off function and leave me with nothing. My ajax function looks that way :

```
function loadSupportList(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : url,
        data : {
            userId : userId,
            sessionId : sessionId
        },
        success : function(data) {
            callback(data['tasks']);
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error, status = " + textStatus + ", " + "error thrown: "
                    + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

And i dont know what to change, to ignore(?) or made some json with ('success')? Is there a way? Thanks for your time.

I make something silly, but its work so it's not silly

```
    loadTasks(function(tasks) {
    taskhtml = whatStatus(tasks);
    $("#devtask-table").html(
            titleDraw() + "<tbody>" + supporthtml + taskhtml
                    + "</tbody>");
    loadSupportList(function(tasks) {
        supporthtml = support(tasks);
        $("#devtask-table").html(
                titleDraw() + "<tbody>" + supporthtml + taskhtml
                        + "</tbody>");
        hideCurtain();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you describe your problem in other way? I don't understand it correctly

Comment: what does loadTasks look like? on which one are you getting the error ?

Comment: I have table that have records from two diffrent source and connect them at $("#devtask-table").html(here) but when there is no records in for example loadSupportList() then it jump of loadSupportList(function(tasks) {} and never get to devtask-table.

Comment: Its looke same as loadSupportList only url change.

Comment: Use "Pause on Exceptions" in Chrome Developer Tools (with Async box checked!) so that the debugger can stop exactly where the problem is.

Comment: But i know where is a problem, this ajax return error, and it should but i dont know how to ignore it and move on.

Answer (score 1):

assuming tasks returns an array... update your `loadSupportList` function like this..

```
    success : function(data) {
        var ret = [];
        if(
            'object' == typeof data && 
            'undefined' != typeof data.tasks
        ) ret = data.tasks;
        callback(ret);
    }
```

Comment: it still leave loadSupportList(function(tasks){} tasks returns json.

Comment: technically raw json would either evaluate to an object or an array. you mean it returns a json *string* or what?